# onclick in the innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I wish I could add a button in an innerHTML that when clicked on it starts a function.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.innerHTML += "<button onclick="
myFunction()
">Click me</button> ";


function myFunction() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<div id="test"> </div>
```

I would like to understand why this code does not work this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use single/double qoutes, or escape them.

```
test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click me</button> ";
```

OR

```
test.innerHTML += "<button onclick=\"myFunction()\">Click me</button> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few solutions here:

**1.** You use single quotes inside double quotes or vice versa

**2.** You escape the single/double quotes inside the string when using only single or double quotes

**3.** use jquery append

NOTE: witch JQuery append you can just insert another element of the HTML, so no worries about having wrong quotes/escaping characters etc..

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click me</button>";


var test2 = document.getElementById('test2');
test2.innerHTML += "<button onclick=\"myFunction()\">Click me</button>";

$("#test3").append("<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click me</button>");


$("#test4").append($("#btn"));


function myFunction() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

```css
#test4 #btn {
 display: block;
}

#btn{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1:
<div id="test"></div>
2:
<div id="test2"></div>
3:
<div id="test3"></div>
4:
<div id="test4"></div>


<button id="btn" onclick='myFunction()'>Click me</button>
```